# operate_let.sh: let: not found, and i add #!/bin/sh in my .sh script , but i also can't work, how can i make it work?

Tags: shell, ubuntu

This is my code, the name of it is operate_let.sh. when i run (sh operate_let.sh) in the Terminal. there are some error:operate_let.sh: 11: operate_let.sh: let: not found

can anybody help me ?

```
#!/bin/sh
#let 执行算术操作经常使用的方法
i=10
j=20
k=3

#执行算术运算
let res1=$i+$j+$k
let res2=$j-$i-$k
let res3=$i*$j*$k
let res4=$i*$j/$k

#输出运算结果
echo "i+j+k=$res1"
echo "j-i-k=$res2"
echo "i*j*k=$res3"
echo "i*j/k=$res4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using #!/bin/bash instead of #!/bin/sh to make sure it is using the right shell. Let isn't defined in all of them, it's working with bash.

Answer (score 0):

I just find when i run bash operate_let.sh, It works.like this:

```
magic@magic-VirtualBox:$ bash operate_let.sh
i+j+k=33
j-i-k=7
i*j*k=600
i*j/k=66
```

Can somebody explain this for me?

Comment: You'd better not post a question here as an answer, try appending it below your question.